# Ubuntu Touch- Problem with unlocking bootloader using adb

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, bootloader, samsung, adb

I was following [this tutorial](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/?_ga=1.117174214.196319495.1490544984)

and I've got problem in rebooting the device in bootloader mode.

I have found another way to get there <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume up</kbd> but adb does not see my device then. Step I'm stuck on is about unlocking bootloader. I'm using Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (gt-p5100).

Comment: well `adb` commands do not work in bootloader (aka fastboot mode) you have to use `fastboot` commands, for eg `fastboot devices` to see the list of attached devices in fastboot mode

Comment: fastboot also not working

Comment: Did you install adb fastboot drivers in pc? Where are you running these commands? Did you downloaded platform tools?